# SublimeText3 - Highlight nested SQL

Tags: sql, sublimetext3, datagrip

I use SublimeText3 for writing SQL. I deal with really long multi-layer nested CASE statements.
It is challenging to figure out which WHEN clauses belong to which layer of the nested CASE statement.
I usually copy the code in DataGrip and then click on CASE which then highlights all the WHEN under that CASE and also highlights END of the CASE statement which makes it very convenient to debug code

Is there something similar in Sublimetext3 ?

Comment: Why not just using DataGrip? :)

Comment: Two reasons:Our DataGrip license is being taken away because we are moving to Snowflake and I have Github integrated with SublimeText

Comment: But DataGrip supports Snowflake as well

Comment: Yeah, I know. But our license is being taken away. So we are now limited to just the Snowflake UI